# Sort a list alphabetically and retrieve initial index in python

Tags: python, sorting, indexing, alphabetical-sort

I've been trying to sort a list of names alphabetically, let's say:

```
list=['Bob','Alice','Charlie']
print(list.index('Alice'))
1
```

However I'd also like to keep track of the original indexes, so this won't work:

```
list.sort()
print(list)
['Alice','Bob','Charlie']
print(list.index('Alice'))
0
```

After sorting the indexes changed; is there any way of keeping track of the original indexes? I've checked other similar questions and numpy has a solution, but not useful for str variables.

Comment: You can create a copy of the original list and use it for referring to original indexes.

Comment: is your list unique ?

Comment: Kinda depends on *why* you want that and what you plan to do with that information.

Comment: How can I do that? I tried to make a copy, say templist=list, but modifying elements in list also changes the ones in templist.

Comment: ON 'why', I'm trying to make a list of members, each one with a unique ID number... And I'd like that number to be associated with the list index

Answer (score 5):

Just sort the reversed `(index, name)` tuples from `enumerate` to keep track of the elements and their indices:

```
>>> names = ['Bob','Alice','Charlie']
>>> sorted((name, index) for index, name in enumerate(names))
[('Alice', 1), ('Bob', 0), ('Charlie', 2)]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
l = ['Bob','Alice','Charlie']
e = enumerate(l) # creates a generator of [(0, 'Bob'), (1, 'Alice'), (2, 'Charlie')]
sl = sorted(e, key=lambda x: x[1]) # [(1, 'Alice'), (0, 'Bob'), (2, 'Charlie')]
```

Answer (score 3):

You may create another list of indices and sort that one, leaving the original untouched:

```
>>> a = ['Bob', 'Alice', 'Charlie']
>>> idx = range(len(a))
>>> idx
[0, 1, 2]
>>> sorted( idx, key=lambda x : a[x] )
[1, 0, 2]
>>>
```

Comment: `range()` returns a list?

Comment: @PalakKumarJha yes, unless you use python 3 or something

Answer (score 1):

You could create a nested dictionary of sorts to hold the original index and sorted value.

First I would recommend to use a proper name for your list object, list is a keyword in python.

```
names=['Bob','Alice','Charlie']

name_dict = {name : {'unsorted' : idx} for idx,name in enumerate(names)}

for sorted_idx, name in enumerate(sorted(names)):
    name_dict[name].update({'sorted' : sorted_idx})
```

---

```
print(name_dict['Bob']['sorted'])
1
print(name_dict['Bob']['unsorted'])
0

print(name_dict)

{'Bob': {'unsorted': 0, 'sorted': 1},
 'Alice': {'unsorted': 1, 'sorted': 0},
 'Charlie': {'unsorted': 2, 'sorted': 2}}
```

Comment: I think this is a good demonstration of what happens before and after sorting.

Comment: Thanks, now that i think about it, your answer is much more succint @RoadRunner cool to see another Microsoft Azure nut around :)

Answer (score 0):

Sort a list alphabetically and retrieve initial index elemnt in python

```
l=['Bob','Alice','Charlie']
def sort_and_get_first_element(list1):
    list1.sort()
    return list1[0]
print sort_and_get_first_element(l)
```

Comment: I am not going to downvote because this, but this does not answer the question asked at all. You are just returning the first item from the sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can keep track of initial index but with different data structure

```
a = ['Bob','Alice','Charlie']
l = sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda i: i[1])
print(l)
```

Now the sorted list that keep track of initial index is,

```
[(1, 'Alice'), (0, 'Bob'), (2, 'Charlie')]
```